# \DeclareNumChars and commands in page field

Tags: biblatex, biber

I am creating a tools to manage manuscripts in classical philology. These manuscript are paginated by folio, each folio have a recto and a verso. So when citing a manuscript, we says the folio and the information about recto or verso.

For example :

> Paris, BNF, Grec 1470, f. 23r-25v

Means "Greek manuscript 1470 of BNF in Paris, folio 23 recto to folio 25 verso.

I can declare new characters in numbering of page with :

```
\DeclareNumChars*{vr}
```

That works fine : the pagination prefix (folio, which I have declared) is correctly put.

However, as I don't know how I would like to print the folio information, I made two command : `\recto` and `\verso`, that I used in my page field.

```
\newcommand{\recto}{r}
\newcommand{\verso}{v}
```

Which I hope to change it, if needed, by

```
\newcommand{\recto}{\textsuperscript{r}}
\newcommand{\verso}{\textsuperscript{v}}
```

However, the use of these command makes `\DeclareNumChars*{vr}` does not work.
Is there any solution ?

Full preamble example :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[citestyle=verbose]{biblatex}
\newcommand{\verso}{v}
\newcommand{\recto}{r}
\DeclareNumChars*{vr}
\bibliography{biblio.bib}
\begin{document}
\cite{P1470}
\end{document}
```

And the file biblio.bib (indeed, it's more complexe, because it's a personnal entrytype)

```
@book{P1470,
   Title={Paris BNF 1470},
   Bookpagination={folio},
   Pages={23\recto-25\verso}
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided a full example including preamble which illustrates what you're trying to do and how it's not working.  My first guess (I've never worked with `\DeclareNumChars`) is that this might be an expansion issue.

Comment: I have completed, but as you can see, it's not very complex and I was thinking my explanation was enough

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution. We must use `NumCheckSetup` to transform these commands to empty commands, at the begining of number testing (see the documentation).

So in my case:

```
\NumCheckSetup{\def\verso{}\def\recto{}}
```

So, when the pages field is tested `23\recto-25\verso` is considered as `23-25`. And my problem is solved.